# Custom PCI bracket with support, for custom PCB?

Tags: pci

I am considering to put a custom PCB card that I made, into my computer.

It won't go on any PCI connector, it plugs in on a USB connector on the motherboard, via a ribbon cable.

I need thou to plug a device to it; which means that either I leave the PCB outside the case, hanging by the ribbon (bad idea), or I could put it in a PCI slot, using a bracket.

The issue is that the brackets that I have, do not have tabs, so I have no way to screw the PCB on them. I was hoping to find something that would allow me to put the PCB on it, and then just fit it in the PCI bracket opening, like this:

http://www.idotpc.com/TheStore/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=1203&idcategory=0

This one won't fit the bill since the holes are too close apart, compared to the one that I have already on the PCB (and can't make more holes).

Do you know if there is a place where they make universal PCI bracket mounting systems for custom PCB? I just need one, so can't even order a custom one (they ask me 120 dollars for one).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you mentioned that it plugs into USB connector.. why not simply buy a normal male USB connector and connect it to your normal USB slot? (Rather than going through the ribbon directly into the motherboard)

Comment: The problem is that the PCB does not have an enclosure; I was planning to keep it inside the case so I don't have to worry about it. I could get an enclosure, but then it would be a cable from the PCB to the USB on the computer, and another cable from the USB device to the PCB...it may work but it would be quite messy.

Comment: @newbiez - Lets be honest any solution is going to be messy.  99.9% of people who have a computer are not connecting a custom PCB board to it.

Comment: PCI Bracket Mounting System exist... for standard sizes. Custom Size PCB will either have to fit those existing sizes, or you can create your own box.. (If you have a friend with a 3D Printer... they can probably print a box for you)

Comment: @Ramhound: that's why I want to put it inside the computer case; the size of the PCB is about the same as a 2.5 hdd, so I am thinking to just grab a used network card and use that as base to support it. We work hard to find solutions and avoid mess...the fact that 99% of people don't do that, doesn't mean that can't be done.

Comment: @Darius: yes; saw some of these solution but the mount covers part of the bracket; so it is not that simple to adapt to it. For the box I have found small ones at Radioshack; but before going in that route I would like to see if I can use the space in the PCI slot

Answer (score 0):

http://www.idotpc.com/TheStore/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=1203&idcategory=0
At this point in time this might have been a product of your whants.

Comment: Could you explain ?